# Memory error in python while using solve function in sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, sympy

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-c41b450be640> in <module>
      4 ni=1e+10
      5 expres=sy.exp(sy.sqrt((0.104*e_si*E_0*sy.log((Nd/ni),2.718))/(q*Nd))-1)
----> 6 print(sy.solvers.solve(expres,Nd))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1169     ###########################################################################
   1170     if bare_f:
-> 1171         solution = _solve(f[0], *symbols, **flags)
   1172     else:
   1173         solution = _solve_system(f, symbols, **flags)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py in _solve(f, *symbols, **flags)
   1525 
   1526         try:
-> 1527             poly = Poly(f_num)
   1528             if poly is None:
   1529                 raise ValueError('could not convert %s to Poly' % f_num)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py in __new__(cls, rep, *gens, **args)
    123                 return cls._from_poly(rep, opt)
    124             else:
--> 125                 return cls._from_expr(rep, opt)
    126 
    127     @classmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py in _from_expr(cls, rep, opt)
    234         """Construct a polynomial from an expression. """
    235         rep, opt = _dict_from_expr(rep, opt)
--> 236         return cls._from_dict(rep, opt)
    237 
    238     def _hashable_content(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polytools.py in _from_dict(cls, rep, opt)
    183                 rep[monom] = domain.convert(coeff)
    184 
--> 185         return cls.new(DMP.from_dict(rep, level, domain), *gens)
    186 
    187     @classmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\polyclasses.py in from_dict(cls, rep, lev, dom)
    275     def from_dict(cls, rep, lev, dom):
    276         """Construct and instance of ``cls`` from a ``dict`` representation. """
--> 277         return cls(dmp_from_dict(rep, lev, dom), dom, lev)
    278 
    279     @classmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\densebasic.py in dmp_from_dict(f, u, K)
   1012 
   1013         if coeff is not None:
-> 1014             h.append(dmp_from_dict(coeff, v, K))
   1015         else:
   1016             h.append(dmp_zero(v))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\densebasic.py in dmp_from_dict(f, u, K)
    992     """
    993     if not u:
--> 994         return dup_from_dict(f, K)
    995     if not f:
    996         return dmp_zero(u)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\polys\densebasic.py in dup_from_dict(f, K)
    945 
    946         for k in range(n, -1, -1):
--> 947             h.append(f.get((k,), K.zero))
    948 
    949     return dup_strip(h)

MemoryError:
```

The above errors appeared when I tried to run the following program. Can someone explain what is a memory error, and how to overcome this problem? The program solves the "express" equation with Nd as a variable using the solve function in sympy library. It should print values of Nd symbol after solving the express equation. This expression is for finding concentration in n-type semi-conductor mos capacitor.

```
import sympy as sy
Nd=sy.symbols('Nd')
q=1.6e-19
ni=1e+10
e_si=11.68
E_0=8.85e-14
expres=sy.sqrt((0.104*e_si*E_0*sy.log((Nd/ni),2.718))/(q*Nd))-1
print(sy.solvers.solve(expres,Nd))
```

Comment: Your expression is of the form `exp(...)`. The `solve` function equates your expression to 0. There is no solution here. Note 1: `log` is already base e, you don't need to specify it. Note 2: Avoid floats as much as possible when using exact mathematics. Rather replace them with symbols and substitute them back once you found a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Now I got it. Could you tell me why there is no solution when it is in the form exp(..). I got the solution only when I removed exp().

Comment: The equation `e^x = 0` makes little sense in the reals or complex numbers. If `x` is real, then `e^x` must be positive. If `x` is complex, then `e^x` must be some non-zero complex number. If we are in the extended reals, then `x=-infinity` will solve it but SymPy mostly assumes it's in the complex domain when you type `sy.symbols('x')`.

Comment: Maybe you made some typo in your expression. As already mentioned, `exp` can only be zero for minus infinity. Also note that sympy always tries to find exact symbolic solutions, which don't make sense when you use floats, especially not when you only use 2 or 3 significant digits.  For floats, sympy's `nsolve` can try to find numeric solutions (`nsolve` uses the multiprecision `mpmath` library).

Comment: Yeah, I made some typo. I thought of exp as something else